# Not able to remove an element from map(NamedValue) while iterating on same map?

Tags: java, collections

Is there any way that I can remove or add element in map I am currently iterating(using iterator) upon. Please suggest.

Comment: This is both off-topic and a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is to do it in two distinct steps.

Pseudocode:

```
function IterateMap(myMap as MapType):
   var myList = new ListType()
   for key, value in myMap:
      if IsBadKey(key):
         myList.Add(key)
      else:
         Process(key, value)
   for badKey in myList:
      myMap.Remove(badKey)
```